# Using Annotation for Authorization Checks in Java

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, web-applications, annotations

I have some methods like the following in my Class:

```
addOrder(long orderId){...}
updateOrder(long orderId, int qty){...}
deleteOrder(long orderId){...}
```

I want add Authorization behavior to them. For example: 
Only if you are owner of the Order, you can updateOrder. 
Only if you are a paid user, you can addOrder.
Only if your Order is in status 'NEW', you can deleteOrder.

What is the best way to do this?
Can we do this using Annotations?

```
@checkAuthorization
addOrder(long orderId){...}

@checkAuthorization
updateOrder(long orderId, int qty){...}

@checkAuthorization
deleteOrder(long orderId){...}
```

The checkAuthorization annotation presence should itself result in a call to a custom method that i would implement where i check if this invocations is allowed or not.

If not Annotations, any other best practice?
If it matters this code exists in a web-application (Struts-1).

Comment: Any answer for this question?

Answer (score 0):

Checks like this could be performed with Aspect Oriented Programming (AOP). A practical implementation is [Spring Security](https://spring.io/projects/spring-security). You can also check [object permissions](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/5.1.6.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#access-control-using-preauthorize-and-postauthorize) with Access Control Lists (ACL) or custom implementations. To do this you can reference parameters with Spring Expression Language:

```
@PreAuthorize("#c.name == authentication.name")
public void doSomething(@P("c") Contact contact);
```